# Is there any polygon select map tool for QgsMapCanvas?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgs

I am trying to create a plugin that has a `QgsMapCanvas` of itself. The question is that I can't seem to find the appropriate library to use polygon select feature in the `QgsMapCanvas`. I know that `iface` has `actionSelect().trigger()` function to implement the required but that allows selection only over the QGIS window and not on the plugin's map canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround to it. To implement `iface.actionSelect().trigger()` map tool in `QgsMapCanvas`, I created a class to initialize `QgsMapToolIdentifyFigure`

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas,QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature
class initLayerFeatureSelectionTool(QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature.__init__(self, self.canvas)
    def keyPressEvent( self, e ):
        pass # disable escape key event to prevent loosing maptool
mapCanvas=QgsMapCanvas() # initialize map canvas
selectLayerFeatureSelectTool=initLayerSelectFeatureSelectionTool(mapCanvas) # initalize QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature
mapCanvas.setMapTool(selectLayerFeatureSelectTool) # set canvas map tool    
selectLayerTool.featureIdentified.connect(loadCoordinatesInPlugin)

@pyqtSlot
def loadCoordinatesInPlugin(feature):
    """ to allow multiple selection remove first line of this function"""
    VectorLayer.removeSelection() 
    VectorLayer.select(feature.id()) #select feature in vector layer
```